# How to get `check-box` value from template to route?

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember page, I don't have the `controller`, but I have the route and hbs files. When a user clicks on the checkbox, how can I retrieve the value (`true/false`) in my route action method?

Here is my template :

```
<div class="agreementContent">
    {{rdc-checkbox label="*I agree to the <a href='#' (action 'goToTerms')> Terms & Conditions </a>" action="acceptTerms" checked=terms}}
</div>
```

My route file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params){
        console.log('got the model', params );
        return this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id );
    },
    actions:{
        goToTerms(){
            console.log("confirm clicked");
        },
        acceptTerms( event ){
            const value = this.get('terms');
            console.log("accept Terms clicked", value );//undefined
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Tried like :

```
actions:{
    goToTerms(){
        console.log("confirm clicked");
    },
    acceptTerms( event ){
        console.log("accept Terms clicked", this.modelFor(this.routeName) );// gives the model value as null
    }
}
```

Comment: The `rdc-checkbox` component, is this a public component? Does it have a github page or something?

Comment: @JacobvanLingen No that's just created for my project purpose only. still i am ready to use the any of the checkbox if requries

Comment: event.target.value